# How can I fix it

Tags: github

error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 4164 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

when i'm try trying to clon from githab i face this problem.i was try it (git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000) but des'nt work it